# Error connecting to freeIPA demo ldap server using python3-ldap

Tags: python, python-3.4, python-ldap

> This is the sample code copied  from the documentation page  of
>   **ldap3** *http://ldap3.readthedocs.io/tutorial_searches.html#finding-entries*. I am trying to make a connection to ldap but its not working for the
>   free test ldap and even my own ldap server.

**testing.py**

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL

server = Server('ipa.demo1.freeipa.org', get_info=ALL)
conn = Connection(server, 'uid=admin,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=demo1,dc=freeipa,dc=org', 'Secret123', auto_bind=True)
conn.search('dc=demo1,dc=freeipa,dc=org', '(objectclass=person)')
print(conn.entries)
```

For test purpose trying to connect to the testing server and this is the common error I get when trying to make  the connections.

**Error Message**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testingldap.py", line 9, in <module>
    conn = Connection(server, 'uid=admin,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=demo1,dc=freeipa,dc=org', 'Secret123', auto_bind=True)
  File "/home/tara/env3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ldap3/core/connection.py", line 278, in __init__
    self.bind(read_server_info=True)
  File "/home/tara/env3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ldap3/core/connection.py", line 427, in bind
    response = self.post_send_single_response(self.send('bindRequest', request, controls))
  File "/home/tara/env3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ldap3/strategy/sync.py", line 122, in post_send_single_response
    responses, result = self.get_response(message_id)
  File "/home/tara/env3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ldap3/strategy/base.py", line 298, in get_response
    responses = self._get_response(message_id)
  File "/home/tara/env3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ldap3/strategy/sync.py", line 168, in _get_response
    dict_response = self.decode_response(ldap_resp)
  File "/home/tara/env3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ldap3/strategy/base.py", line 403, in decode_response
    result = bind_response_to_dict(component)
  File "/home/tara/env3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ldap3/operation/bind.py", line 119, in bind_response_to_dict
    'saslCreds': bytes(response['serverSaslCreds']) if response['serverSaslCreds'] is not None else None}
  File "/home/tara/env3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyasn1/type/univ.py", line 984, in __bytes__
    return bytes(self._value)
  File "/home/tara/env3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyasn1/type/base.py", line 164, in plug
    raise error.PyAsn1Error('Uninitialized ASN.1 value ("%s" attribute looked up)' % name)
pyasn1.error.PyAsn1Error: Uninitialized ASN.1 value ("__len__" attribute looked up)
```

Where is the problem exactly